# printf of char* gets Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I'm Trying to read from a socket and print to stdout using printf (a must);

However I get a Segmentation Fault every time I read a specific file (an HTML) from the sane web site.

Please, take a look at this code and tell me what wrong.

```
int total_read = 0;
 char* read_buff = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
 char* response_data = NULL;
 if (read_buff == NULL){
  perror("malloc");
  exit(1);
 }
 while((nbytes = read(fd, read_buff, BUF_SIZE)) > 0){
  int former_total = total_read;
  total_read += nbytes;
  response_data = realloc(response_data, total_read);
  memmove(response_data + former_total, read_buff, nbytes); //start writing at the end of spot before the increase.
 }
 if (nbytes < 0){
  perror("read");
  exit(1);
 }

 printf(response_data);
```

Thank You.

Comment: You should click the checkmark-shaped icon by answers that solve your problem.

Comment: What's likely to be in response_data? If it contains printf-formatting characters, printf will try to access some parameters you've not passed. Try puts instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`response_data` is probably not NUL (`'\0'`) terminated, so `printf` continues past the end of the string.  Or possibly it contains a `%` directive but `printf` can't find further arguments.

Instead, tell `printf` how far to read, and *not* to interpret any `%` directives in the string.

```
printf("%.*s", total_read, response_data);
```

Note that if `response_data` contains an embedded NUL, `printf` will stop there even if `total_read` is longer.

Comment: One correction is: printf("%.*s", total_read, response_data); (a dont before the asterisk).

Comment: @Luis: Only matters if `response_data` has an embedded NUL, where `%*s` pads with spaces, `%-*s` pads with spaces on the other side, and `%.*s` does no padding at all.  Depends on what OP wants…

Comment: but the precision for string format is not the maximum number of characters to be printed ?.

Comment: @Luis: Oh, drat.  You're right, and I'm amazed you're the first one to catch it.  Thanks :)

Comment: Thank You,

It works. Can you explain why the simple way got me a Segmentation Fault.

Answer (score 1):

What's likely to be in `response_data`? If it contains printf-formatting characters (i.e. `%` followed by one of the usual options), `printf` will try to access some parameters you've not passed, and a segmentation fault is quite likely. Try `puts` instead?

If you must use printf, do `printf("%s", response_data)` (and NUL-terminate it first)

Comment: Thank You,

This works. I still considering which of the forms to use.

Answer (score -2):

My understanding from your post is that the response is the HTML data.
And since it is text you attempt to print it. Do not use printf the way you do.
Instead do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < total_read; i++)
   putc(response_data[i],stdout);
```

Comment: Putc is still not the way to do this. You're reimplementing what printf "%.s" wil do.